# Best practice for calling two different endpoints for a widget?

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter

What is considered the best practice to use when two different endpoints are needed in order to render something? Right now I'm nesting FutureBuilders but that doesn't seem ideal.

Example:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new FutureBuilder(
    future: Firestore.instance.collection('games').document(this.documentId).get(),
    builder: (BuildContext gamesContext, AsyncSnapshot gamesSnapshot) {
      return new FutureBuilder(
        future: Firestore.instance.collection('profiles').document(gamesSnapshot.data['authorId']).get(),
        builder: (BuildContext profilesContext, AsyncSnapshot profilesSnapshot) {
          // Code goes here.
        }
      ),
    }
  ),
}
```

There's got to be a cleaner way, right?

Comment: You can use a `FutureBuilder` with `Future.wait()` to wait for multiple futures to complete.

Comment: If you want more information, add the code that demonstrates what you tried and what you try to accomplish.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Example added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a single `FutureBuilder`:

```
Future<AsyncSnapshot> getProfiles() async {
  var gamesSnapshot = await Firestore.instance.collection('games').document(this.documentId).get();
  return Firestore.instance.collection('profiles').document(gamesSnapshot.data['authorId']).get()
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new FutureBuilder(
    future: getProfiles(),
    builder: (BuildContext profilesContext, AsyncSnapshot profilesSnapshot) {
      // Code goes here.
    }
  ),
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Just a heads up, Firebase .get() returns a DocumentSnapshot, not an AsyncSnapshot.